# Помогите решить проблему записи в файл

Tags: python

Задача такая: нужно решить 50 квадратных уравнений, для этого надо записать в файл 50 значений в таком виде:

2 5 5

10 4 0

...

Затем работает код решения квадратного уравнения, после в конце каждой строки пишем либо корни, либо нет решений:

2 5 5: нет решений

10 4 0: нет решений

```
import random

with open('pi.txt', 'w') as file:
    for i in range(1, 51):
        file.write(f'{random.randint(1, 10)} {random.randint(1, 10)} {random.randint(1, 10)}\n')

v = open('pi.txt', 'r')
lines = v.readlines()

for line in lines:
    q = [int(x) for x in line.split()]
    m = f'{q[0]} {q[1]} {q[2]}'

def quadratic_equation(a, b, c):
    D = b ** 2 - 4 * a * c
    if D > 0:
        v.write(m+f' :{round(((-b - D ** (1 / 2)) / (2 * a)),2)}, { round(((-b + D ** (1 / 2)) / (2 * a)),2)}')
    v.write('\n')
    elif D == 0:
        v.write(f'{m} :{round(-b / (2 * a),2)}')
        v.write('\n')
    else:
        v.write(f'{m} :нет решений')
        v.write('\n')

quadratic_equation(q[0], q[1], q[2])
v.close()
```

но при запуске кода ругается на строки `m = f'{q[0]} {q[1]} {q[2]}'` и `v.write(f'{m} :нет решений')`, выдаёт ошибку not writable.

Я попытался её исправить изменив в строке `v = open('pi.txt', 'r')` r на r+, ошибок не выдало, 50 значений в файл записало, но почему-то вывело результат только самой последней паре чисел. Подскажите как исправить эту проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не критично итог писать в тот же файл.

```py
import random

def quadratic_equation(a, b, c):
    m = f'{a} {b} {c}'
    with open('pi2.txt', 'a') as v:
        D = b ** 2 - 4 * a * c
        if D > 0:
            v.write(m+f' :{round(((-b - D ** (1 / 2)) / (2 * a)),2)}, { round(((-b + D ** (1 / 2)) / (2 * a)),2)}')
            v.write('\n')
        elif D == 0:
            v.write(f'{m} :{round(-b / (2 * a),2)}')
            v.write('\n')
        else:
            v.write(f'{m} :нет решений')
            v.write('\n')

with open('pi.txt', 'w') as file:
    for i in range(1, 51):
        file.write(f'{random.randint(1, 10)} {random.randint(1, 10)} {random.randint(1, 10)}\n')

with open('pi.txt', 'r+') as  v:
    lines = v.readlines()

for line in lines:
    q = [int(x) for x in line.split()]
    quadratic_equation(q[0], q[1], q[2])
```

P.S. Если будет время постараюсь попозже переписать весь код.